# как сделать отскок мяча от игрока?

Tags: python, pygame

я пытался сделать отскок мяча от игрока на pygame, но когда мяч сталкивается из игроком, мяч попросту исчезает, не можете подсказать что мне делать?

вот код мячы:

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
    self.image.fill(WHITE)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
    self.speedx = 5
    self.speedy = 0
    
def update(self):
    self.rect.x += self.speedx
    self.rect.y += self.speedy
    if last_s = True:
        self.speedx = -5
    if self.rect.left > WIDTH:
        self.speedx = -5
    if self.rect.right < 0:
        self.speedx = 5
    if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
        self.speedy = -5
    if self.rect.bottom < 0:
        self.speedy = 5
```

вот код столкновения:

```
    last_s = False
    
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, balls, True)
    for hit in hits:
         last_s = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спрайт пропадает потому, что 3-им аргументом в `hits` вы указали `True`, который отвечает за `dokill`

Из документации:

```
spritecollide(sprite, group, dokill, collided = None) -> Sprite_list
```